# How to make LaunchScreen.storyboard keep portiait on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

Set root VC  and *info.plist* only support portrait work fine with iPhone, but iPad not. Please gave me the same information. Thank you very much.

Comment: what happens in ipad ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below settings in you project.
Go to Project-> Select Target-> Select General Tab -> scroll to down to deployment info and use the settings as in below image -
[image]

You will always get a Portrait mode for both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: I already use this setting. It make app keep Protrait. But not the LanchScreen